# How to extract and resolve values within linked config file

Tags: c#

I have a file called log.config which is referenced in the appSettings part of App.config.

Within log.config I have a line (see below for where this line fits into log.config) ...

```
<file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="${ALLUSERSPROFILE}/dir1/Log/log.txt" />
```

I want to retrieve the full pathname of log.txt. I.e. to extract the value and resolve the variable. I.e. to get the string:

```
C:\ProgramData\dir1\Log\log.txt
```

is this possible? (I have tried fiddling about with `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager` but cant figure out how to get it.)

log.config...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net"
       type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
  </configSections>
  <log4net>

    <appender name="HourlyAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="${ALLUSERSPROFILE}/dir1/Log/log.txt" />
      <appendToFile value="false" />
      . . . . .
```

Comment: Have a look at this blog post and see if it helps you; http://learncsharp.org/how-to-store-and-retrieve-data-in-an-application-or-web-configuration-file/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way log4net does resolve its variables is using `OptionConverter.SubstituteVariables`, and in case of environment variables it just uses `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables()` to get a dictionary of all of them.

So you could use:

```
log4net.Util.OptionConverter.SubstituteVariables("${ALLUSERSPROFILE}/dir1/Log/log.txt", Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables())
```

and the result will be `C:\ProgramData/dir1/Log/log.txt`.

Another option is to resolve the environment variable yourself using a regex to capture it and `Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables` to expand it:

```
Regex.Replace("${ALLUSERSPROFILE}/dir1/Log/log.txt",
              @"\$\{(.*)\}",
              m => Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(String.Format("%{0}%", m.Groups[1])))
```

---

To read this part of the config file, you would usually create an appropriate `IConfigurationSectionHandler`.

log4net does provide one (`Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler`), but it's not useful for you here. But since the configuration is a XML, we can make use of the `SelectSingleNode` method:

```
XmlElement config = (XmlElement)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("log4net");
string path = config.SelectSingleNode("appender/file").Attributes["value"].Value;
```

Comment: Thanks @sloth, This answers the second part of the question. I also need to extract the string `"${ALLUSERSPROFILE}/dir1/Log/log.txt" from the config file. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: @spiderplant0 Sorry, I assumed you can already read the string from the config file. I updated my answer.